# Reply to someone going on a summer holiday

Tags: word-choice

If my friend say "I am going to a beautiful island this summer holiday."  Can I say "Enjoy youself"?

Is my reply proper?

Comment: You say, "Enjoy you**r**self."

Comment: Yep. "Enjoy yourself" would be an appropriate response.

Comment: Yep that's fine. In fact I think your response is one of the best possible.

Answer (score 1):

In case it wasn't a typo, you need to use the pronoun [*you**r**self*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yourself). Yes, "enjoy yourself" is fine. At least in the US, some other common expressions are

> 1. Have fun!
> 2. Have a good time!
> 3. Have a nice trip!

Of course, you can replace *good* and *nice* with other adjectives like *great* or *wonderful*.